# Executing a large number of concurrent functions on AWS lambda (for example broadcast push notifications)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, aws-lambda

I have an AWS lambda function that sends push to a single device like this:

```
var push = function(payload, ctx){
  var apn = require('apn'); 
  var connection = new apn.Connection(options);
  var token = "(MY TOKEN HERE)";
  var device = new apn.Device(token);

  var note = new apn.Notification();
  note.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600;
  note.badge = 3;
  note.sound = "ding.wav";
  note.alert = "Hello";
  note.payload = payload;
  connection.on('transmitted', function(){
    ctx.succeed({ "response": "OK" })
  });
  connection.pushNotification(note, device);
}
```

Now I want to expand it so I can send broadcast pushes to a group of devices.

At first I thought it would be a simple as putting them all in a for loop, but on second thought it wouldn't work because the `ctx.succeed` part shouldn't return until all push has been sent. Also, if I wait until all pushes have been sent, then the request would take too long and may even time out.

What is the right way to execute a large number of concurrent requests like this?

Comment: How many concurrent requests are we talking about? You could either run them asynchronously within a single Lambda execution, or run each one as a separate Lambda execution, or some combination of both approaches.

Comment: How about a million? How does asynchronous lambda execution work? More specifically, how does one go about executing a function asynchronously without having lambda throw the "Process exited before completing request" error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into the [Async library for NodeJS](https://github.com/caolan/async). This is a common thing to do in NodeJS, not just in AWS Lambda functions. In Lambda you would use this to execute many async tasks, and wait to call `ctx.succeed()` until all the async calls have completed.

For a million calls you will still need to batch those up. I think you should look into adding all these tasks as items in a [Kinesis stream](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/streams/), which could then send batches of these tasks to your Lambda function. It could be configured to spin up many concurrent instances of your Lambda function, each processing a batch.